# Output specific line huge text file

Tags: bash, text

I have a sql dump with 300mb that gives me an error on specific line.

But that line is in the middle of the file. What is the best approach?

`head -n middleLine dump.sql > output`?

Or can i output only the line i need?

Comment: do you need what's after this line as well or just what's before?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could use `sed -n -e 123456p your.dump`  to print line 123456

Comment: great! thank you. i actually use `sed -n 123,130p my.dump` to output line range!

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but it seems to me bad style to skip the `-e`. I am also regularly quoting sed command after `-e` since it often contains various strange :-) characters... I would write it `sed -n -e '123,130 p' my.dump`.

Answer (score 24):

If the file is long, consider using

```
sed -n 'X{p;q}' file
```

Where X is the line number. It will stop reading the file after reaching that line.

Comment: On some systems, like osx, it needs an extra semicolon: `sed -n 'X{p;q;}' file`

Answer (score 10):

If `sed` is too slow for your taste you may also use

```
cat $THE_FILE | head -n $DESIRED_LINE | tail -n 1
```

Comment: If I run something like: "started=`date +%s%3N` ; for i in {1..500} ; do echo "$longlist" | sed -n 10p ; done ; stoped=`date +%s%3N` ; echo "scale=3 ; ($stoped - $started)/1000" | bc" and compare to the same but with head -n 10 | tail -n 1 , sed is faster in my system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed:

```
sed -n "x p" dump.sql
```

where `x` is the line number.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 'X!d;q' file
```

where X is the line number.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done with Perl:

```
perl -wnl -e '$. == 4444444 and print and exit;' FILENAME.sql
```

4444444 being the line number you wish to print.

Comment: Also, I see you wanted a full range of lines.  This can also be done with Perl:

`perl -wnl -e '1000 <= $. and $. <= 4444 and print;' FILENAME.sql`

Where 1000 is the first line desired in the range and 4444 is the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `awk` like:

```
awk 'NR==YOUR_LINE_NO{print}' file_name
```

Answer (score -4):

If you know a phrase on that line I would use `grep`. If the phrase is "errortext" use:

```
$ cat dump.sql | grep "errortext"
```

Comment: this isn't what i ask. This will output every "errortext" on the file, not the line i need output.

Comment: More over cat | grep is useless while grep can handle files as well. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html